# Why does い become く?

Tags: adjectives

I noticed many i-adjectives ending with く. I need to know why that happens.

いつか、あなたは背が**高く**なるでしょう。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply because that is how you use i-adjective.

i-adjectives

> 高**い** -> tall
>   高**くない** -> not tall
>   高**くなる** -> become tall

na-adjectives

> すてき -> lovely
>   すてき**じゃない** -> not lovely
>   すてき**になる** -> become lovely

Answer (score 1):

Specifically, what's happening is that you're going from the adjective form to the adverb form. This can seem a bit weird when you think you're just trying to make a negative form or something, but that's how it works - roughly speaking, you're going from "takai" = "tall" to "takaku nai" = "not in a tall fashion" = "not tall".

i-adjectives behave a bit more like verbs in their conjugations, while na-adjectives behave a bit more like nouns, in that when you do stuff with an i-adjective you directly mess around with the ending, while with na-adjectives you leave the word untouched and just use particles and verbs to do all the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, changing the い to a く turns the adjective into an adverb.

> [速]{はや}**い** = quick
>   [速]{はや}**く** = quickly

As mentioned by [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/40760/18582), this is also used to make the negative form of い adjectives:

> [小]{ちい}さ**い** = small
>   [小]{ちい}さ**くない** = not small